# How are an object's instance methods used and stored?

Tags: java, class, linked-list, heap-memory, stack-memory

Let’s say in my main method I have the line of code `LinkedList<E> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<>()`, so now I have a reference/pointer variable named `myLinkedList1` to an object (and the constructor is stored in its own LinkedList class in another `.java` file not the same `.java` file the main method is in).

And now I make another reference/pointer variable named `myLinkedList2`. I use the method `addLast(E newElement)` (this method is stored in the `LinkedList` class of course), but I only use it on `myLinkedList1` (so it is `myLinkedList.addLast(E newElement)`), how does the JVM know to use this method only on `myLinkedList1` and not `myLinkedList2`, are the objects methods stored in the heap with it? I thought they were put on the stack.

Comment: Just a hint here: try to avoid *explaining* your code. Human language is ambiguous. Always try to give a [mcve]. Less words, more code ;-)

Comment: They are neither 'on the heap with it' nor 'on the stack'. They are in the heap with the *class.* The JVM knows to invoke `myLinkedList.addLast()` because that's what you told it in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object, in memory, contains the following information:

- A pointer that points at the actual class that this object is an instance of.
- Enough room for all the fields. Given that java is reference based, every field is at most 64 bit - they're all fixed size, so this is not complicated.
- Other stuff which isn't relevant for your question.

Crucially they **do not contain any methods, at all**.

> I thought they were put on the stack.

Methods? On the stack? That makes no sense. You must be misinformed. Methods aren't on the stack. They aren't really in heap either. They live as singletons in the class definition which is loaded only once for any class. On modern JVMs, those technically do live in the heap, but, crucially, nowhere near the heap space dedicated to storing your object. They live in the heap space dedicated to storing the definition (the bytecode, or rather, the transformed, hotspotted, etc bytecode) of the class. No matter how many LinkedList instances you make, there's only one LinkedList class, so 1 million LinkedList instances still means you only have the actual body content of the `addLast` method stored once in memory. Yes, `addLast` is an instance method. There's still only one copy of it in memory (unlike instance fields; each instance has its own copy of each non-static field).

Any given class is loaded *at most once* for the entire JVM (why load it more than once? These things are constant, it'd be a waste of memory). A class contains **all methods** (instance and static).

In fact, there is, as far as a method is concerned, no different at all between static and non-static methods as far as the JVM is concerned. An instance method simply has as first argument its 'receiver' - for example, `String`'s `toLowerCase()` method is a method that takes 1 argument, of type `String`. There is *very little* difference between:

```
public String toLowerCase() {
  return this.doTheThing();
}
```

and

```
public static String toLowerCase(String in) {
  return in.doTheThing();
}
```

So, when you write, in java, `foo.bar();`, you get 2 unrelated steps: First, `javac` turns it into bytecode, which is stored in a class file. Then, 5 days later on a completely different machine, someone runs your class file and then the JVM sees the bytecode and runs it.

`javac` first tries to figure out which precise `bar()` you are calling there, by checking what the type of `foo` is. Once `javac` figures that out, you end up with the bytecode:

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL com.pkg.FullTypeOfWhateverFooIsThere :: bar :: ()V
```

That third bit is the 'signature' (the parameter types and return types, which in java are an inherent part of a method's identity). That's it - the arguments to all things are on the stack. This particular method has one argument (the receiver - something that is an instance of `com.pkg.FullTypeOfWhateverFooIsThere`), which will have to be on the stack. `javac` ensures it is true. The JVM checks the bytecode and if it can't confirm it is true, it will reject the class file with a VerifierError (this cannot happen unless you manually mess with the bytecode, or have a corrupt disk).

Then, the JVM 'follows the pointer' and checks what that first argument's *actual* type is, and will then find the loaded class that represents that precise type. It then checks **that class** (and not `com.pkg.FullTypeOfWhateverFooIsThere` - at least, not if the actual class is a subclass) for a method named `foo` with signature `()V`. If it finds it, it runs it. If it doesn't, it goes up one class in the hierarchy and keeps looking for `foo::()V` until it finds it (which it will, otherwise your code wouldn't have compiled in the first place).

When the code for `addLast` runs, there are 2 things on the stack as that method begins execution:

1. An instance of `LinkedList` or some subclass thereof.
2. A new element of type Object. (at the JVM level, generics are erased).

The method can do its work just fine with that; LinkedLists have fields that store this data, the code of addLast will interact with these fields in order to do what its javadoc says it should do. Specifically, a LinkedList has a 'head' field that points at a node that contains a reference to the object (that'll be the first object in the list) and a pointer to another node. The addLast code keeps looping, grabbing the 'next pointer', until the next pointer is null. At that point it makes a new Node object, sets its 'value' to that second thing on the stack, and then updates the 'next' pointer of the last visited node to point at this newly created one, and then it is done.

Hence:

- All that the JVM needs to 'find' the `addLast` code, is to know which method was intended (which is in the bytecode), and a pointer to the singleton 'loaded class' in memory for the actual type that is top-of-stack (well, below the parameters) when the INVOKEVIRTUAL command is called, which is easy, as all objects have a pointer to it, so that's just a matter of looking it up. Thus, the JVM can execute addLast.
- All that the `addLast` code needs to know which list to operate on, is.. the list. The receiver is passed as first parameter: `foo.addLast(elem)` ends up being called with the stack having first `foo` and then `elem` on it. This'd be no different from a static method having signature (`addLast(LinkedList<E> list, E elem)`) - any invocations to such a method would have 2 things on stack as well when they begin execution (static methods don't have a receiver, they *just* have their params on stack).

Comment: First off, Thank you for the extensive answer, it helped a lot. Second, I have a few questions about things you brought up in your answer! I thought methods were stored on the stack-memory, I see now that this is not true, but I think I know what tripped me up. [Visualization of Stack and Heap memory](https://www.journaldev.com/4098/java-heap-space-vs-stack-memory), this article shows a picture (and steps below it) of the method `main()` and `foo()` going on the stack. It even says in the steps below that these methods are being put on the stack. So using their example would, lets say,

Comment: **Part 2:** it having an area to the left of the `Stack Memory` that is called something else like `Call Stack` (which ive seen elsewhere that has the methods inside of it) also be wrong. [Example of Call Stack here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap). I have another question, but I would like your insight on this first.

Comment: The methods aren't on the stack. The pointers to them are. If you are in method A and halfway through you call `System.out.println()`, execution jumps to that method. When println is done doing its thing, how does it know to continue where we were in the middle of method A? Because that location ('in the middle of method A') is on the stack. the content of method A itself isn't. Just a pointer.

Comment: Ah, so what you are saying is, just like objects stored in the `heap` have pointers/reference variables (like `foo` or `myList`), methods do as well? So when a line of code says `foo.addLast(elem)` that `addLast(elem)` is actually just a pointer of its own to the somewhere in memory that the methods are "stored"?

Comment: So in this oversimplified visual of the JVM([Visualization of Stack and Heap memory](https://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Java-Heap-Stack-Memory.png)) I am confused because why when the method of an object is used for `mem.foo(obj)` it puts the methods reference/pointer on the left area were the `Stack` is, but when when the program goes to the line that says `String str = param.toString()` (`param` being the same reference/pointer to the address of the object that `obj` points to) there is a little `toString()` in the heap on the right. Is this just to help visualize?

Comment: Oh wow I think I realized my mistake, you mean the pointers to the methods are the `main()` and `foo()` on the stack memory on the left.

Comment: When code goes _to_ `addLast`, it's exactly as my answer describes. But when the addList method is done and it is time to return back to your code - THAT is a pointer that is on the stack.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes so much sense, I also did a lot of supplemental reading on the JRE, JVM, JDK, and the Java Architecture in general. Which helped me understand bytecode, and source codes journey from getting compiled into bytecode -> then the JIT Compiler turning the bytecode into machinecode! Now im going back and re-reading your answer in a new light.

Comment: Just saying: sometimes, when I see a lengthy, deeply technical answer starting ... I kinda know that when I will arrive at the bottom of the answer your user name will show up. Excellent content here!

Comment: @rzwitserloot I came back to this question after doing a couple days of my own research agan, after initially reading your answer. Coming back to this question now I am able to understand it so much better! And realize how extensive you went in your answer (the best I've seen in any of my searches!). So first, I would like to thank you again, and **Second** I just had a huge break through and I want to run it by you to confirm that what I am thinking is correct, and I dont run off thinking I understand it, when I really dont.

Comment: @rzwitserloot **PART 1:** I have realized what **exactly** to a T was stumping me. When you would say, the particular method has one argument "the reciever" which is "an instance of `com.pkg.FullTypeOfWhateverFooIsThere` which is told in the bytecode `INVOKEVIRTUAL com.pkg.FullTypeOfWhateverFooIsThere :: bar :: ()V` . What kept bothering me is nowhere in that bytecode was it saying use `foo1` and not `foo2` , and how would the "reciever" reference/pointer `foo` ever be changed if in the bytecode it only knows `foo`'s type and to only return nothing due to the signature `()V` being void.

Comment: @rzwitserloot **PART 2:** So that throws my initial idea that it was returning anydata somehow back to the reference/pointer variable `foo` which then would send that data to the actual object on the heap it points to, to then change its `head node` or whatever instance variables the object has (I said all of that just so you could see how my mind was thinking the data flowed). But then I found this website that allowed me to post my code in and walk step by step through my own code, and it put up a visualization next to it. And I realized something you said that was way more important

Comment: @rzwitserloot **PART 3:** than I initially thought! You said how in `StringSomething.toLowerCase()` that `return this.doTheThing();` is the same as in a static method `toLowerCase(String in)` doing `return in.doTheThing();`. Using the website visualizer combined with what you said there made it make so much sense. Look at the this picture of the code I used on that website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Zx7.jpg . Would it be correct of me to say that when in the `main()` method `myList1.addFirst("BB")` is called, that in the instance method `addFirst()`

Comment: @rzwitserloot **PART 4:** it knows to add a `node` to the instance `myList1` because the method has a "hidden" parameter of `this` that is just a reference/pointer variable that has the address to the same `MyLinkedList` instance/object in the heap that `myList1` also has? So in reality its not using the pointer `myList1` for anything except using the address it has stored in it to know what instance to make the `this` pointer point to. So would it be fair to think of `myList1` and the `this` in `addFirst()` as sort of two seperate reference/pointer "variables"?

Comment: @rzwitserloot **LAST PART:** and if so, where is the `this` stored in memory?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Would the `this` reciever argument be somewhere on the stack, correct?

Comment: Yup, that's all correct, @ZenPyro

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the object you're calling a method *on* (i.e. the thing before the `.`) as an extra argument to the function. So, conceptually, you can think of `myLinkedList1.addLast(elt)` as being somewhat like

```
LinkedList.addLast(myLinkedList1, elt)
```

so the "invocant" is an additional piece of information passed to the method. Some languages make this explicit. For instance, in Lua, `foo:bar(1)` is *exactly* equivalent to `foo.bar(foo, 1)`, and in Python `foo.bar(1)` is roughly equivalent to `Foo.bar(foo, 1)`. But in Java, this all happens in the background and is a bit more complicated, but conceptually it's the same idea.

Comment: Halfway reading through your reply I was like "Hmmm that sounds an awful like Lua" and lo and behold! I actually have made a few scripts in Lua for Garry's Mod before! So this makes TOO much sense! Its like using the `:` in Lua, I see. I had no clue Java worked in the same way, but _secretly_ Hahahah. I do have one more question though, when does the accessing of the object that is being referenced/pointed to by the variable `foo` actually happen on the heap. Right as the method is called?

Comment: That’s basically how it works in every language which supports some notion of objects and member methods